# Multiple SUM in one Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

i have one small problem...

i have 2 separeted questions for SQL:

1:

```
SELECT SUM(iloscrec*ilosc/100) AS iloscsur, surowiec, Produkt
FROM receptura
  JOIN produkcjadb ON(produkcjadb.Produkt = receptura.kolor)
WHERE data_zakonczenia >= CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY surowiec
```

2:

```
SELECT SUM(ilosccal) AS ilosc, material, jednostka
FROM surowce
WHERE magazyn='G' || magazyn='K' || magazyn='S' || magazyn='P' || magazyn='PROUT' ||
      magazyn='W'  || magazyn='OR'
GROUP BY material
```

And now is my question, Can i connect this 2 question in one and SELECT rows from second question Where they Matched to 1 question WHERE

```
material (secondquestion) = surowiec (from1question)
```

im trying about 5hours but still i have sql syntax error

Thank you in advance !

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Help us help you - Please share your table structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the problem. It would help if you provide a script to create the structures and insert example data and if you show us the expected results, but anyway I guess you just want to use subqueries, e.g. something like this:

```
select ...
from (SELECT SUM(iloscrec*ilosc/100) AS iloscsur, surowiec, Produkt
        FROM receptura
        JOIN produkcjadb ON(produkcjadb.Produkt = receptura.kolor)
       WHERE data_zakonczenia >= CURRENT_DATE
       GROUP BY surowiec
      ) t1 join (
      SELECT SUM(ilosccal) AS ilosc, material, jednostka
        FROM surowce
       WHERE magazyn='G' || magazyn='K' || magazyn='S' || magazyn='P' || magazyn='PROUT' || magazyn='W'  || magazyn='OR'
       GROUP BY material
      ) t2
      on t2.material = t1.surowiec
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, Of course its my fault

```
receptura
-surowiec
-iloscrec
-kolor

produkcjadb
-Produkt
-Ilosc

surowce
-material
-ilosccal
-magazyn
```

and now i need to select

```
1:SUM(iloscrec*ilosc/100) from receptura and produkcjadb where Produkt=kolor
2:SUM(ilosccal) FROM surowce Where magazyn='G' || magazyn='K' || magazyn='S' || magazyn='P' || magazyn='PROUT' ||
  magazyn='W'  || magazyn='OR'
3: matched this row where material(surowce)=surowiec(receptura)
```

There are any chance?